# PowerMock vs Dependency injection

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, powermock

I have a quite complex Android project that I want to start testing quite thoroughly.
So I implemented dependency injection to be able to test several components (I used Kodein for that).
Then I started to write tests, and I found out that I have to use PowerMock, to mock calls to File.create for example.
PowerMock can also mock constructors, factory methods, etc. So basically for testing I can achieve the same result of dependency injection, but without modifying the code.

So my question is:
**If I can mock anything with PowerMock, is there still a reason to implement dependency injection?**

Comment: DI is not for testing only. Write code following best practices and patterns (and not for easy of testing) and then use PowerMock for cases where it is impossible to test otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @tsolakp, I was looking for such kind of answer...
Do you see a really good usage for DI besides testing? I'm aware of the theoretical ability to inject different instances on production, but I've never really see it in practice

Comment: Spring is a good example for DI usage. With DI Spring can inject different implementation or proxy wrappers to your class/interface. Without DI, Spring would have only option of intercepting `new` calls to inject which can be slow, problematic and messy.

Comment: This is an old fallacy that DI is only applicable to unit testing. This is something you need to unlearn. To understand more about the advantages of DI, you should read chapter 1 of [Dependency Injection in .NET. second edition](https://manning.com/seemann2/), which is a [free download](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/1/95f5fad-68ef-41d7-b787-30b9cf635df4/Seemann2_DEidotNET2E_MEAP_V07_ch1.pdf) from the manning.com website. Although the book's code samples are in C#, most (if not all) pattern and practices are applicable to Java and other OOP languages as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are some cases you would use over one than the other, sometimes both. It all depends on what are you testing. Power Mock give you more control on what you can test or cant. While DI give you more direct result.

Here are some examples:
Let's say if you have anonymous class.

```
                @Override
                public Query getQuery() {
                    Query q = Query.empty();
                    if (wp.minSpeed < 0)
                        q = Query.and(q, Query.eq(Speed.Function, WayPoint));
                    else {
                        q = Query.and(q, Query.eq(Speed.Function, Field));
                        q = Query.and(q, Query.eq(Speed.Calc, wp.maxSpeed-wp.minSpeed));
                    }
                    q = Query.and(q, Query.eq(Speed.Id, wp.altitude/greatCircle));
                    return q;
                }
```

Since there is no way to test anonymous class to fulfill your 100% coverage. You should know that power mockito is the only way. You can only imitate the behavior of that class.

However, if you had some tedious class that has multiple classes calls you might want consider using dependency injection to reduce the number of spy / mocking.

Comment: How dependency injection will reduce the number of mocking? I will still have to mock all the dependencies, either via DI or with powermock

Comment: you dont need to mock all classes under it. For example, most common and  annoying thing to mock is the dao classes, because you can have multiple pojos, prepareStatement, result set etc that doesnt really do anything, mockito would be good for that case if you just want verify the result and see your query works as intended but if you want to have the large subset of that dao then you might just consider DI to reduce the task and manual mock you have to do.